# How SlickGrid invalidates/removes rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, memory-leaks, slickgrid

I have a custom formatter that listens to mouse clicks. Works perfectly. But i am in doubt with memory leak case since i know the listener must be removed by invoking "off", or the cell container must be removed by invoking empty().remove().

1. Is SlickGrid aware of that?
2. Will the same method be using during refresh operation. I mean will it remove and re-append the rows?
3. Is there a memory leak (DOM) at https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/blob/master/slick.grid.js#L1555

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SlickGrid is not aware of JQuery events. Here is the issue;
https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/issues/855